How to make a command completely null
How does one redefine a command to ignore all parameters, and not do anything?
Suppose for example that I want to represent the results (of a binomial) in two different ways and then at the end to ignore the command completely.
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\pbinomshort}[3][2]{(#2 + #3)^#1}
\newcommand{\pbinomlong}[3][2]{(#2^#1 + \cdots + #3^#1)}

\begin{document}

Short:
%\let\pbinom\pbinomshort
\newcommand\pbinom\pbinomshort

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Long:
%\let\pbinom\pbinomlong
\renewcommand\pbinom\pbinomlong

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Null:
\renewcommand{\pbinom}{\relax}

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

\end{document}


I would expect the last \renewcommand to work, but it ignores the command and print all  arguments to the file.

You redefined it to absorb 0 args so they're not args just regular input.

Syntax such as
\newcommand\pbinom\pbinomshort

has never been supported. The fact that it seems to work is irrelevant: don't use it.
You also shouldn't use \let, because your “long” and “short” commands have been defined with an optional argument; again,
\let\pbinom\pbinomshort

seems to work, but it actually doesn't.
Finally, in order to make the command to be ignored, you must absorb the same number of arguments.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pbinomshort}[3][2]{(#2 + #3)^{#1}}
\newcommand{\pbinomlong}[3][2]{(#2^{#1} + \dots + #3^{#1})}
\newcommand{\pbinomnull}[3][]{}

\begin{document}

\NewCommandCopy{\pbinom}{\pbinomlong}
\section{Long}

\[
\pbinom{x}{y} \quad \pbinom[4]{a}{b}
\]

\RenewCommandCopy{\pbinom}{\pbinomshort}
\section{Short}

\[
\pbinom{x}{y} \quad \pbinom[4]{a}{b}
\]

\RenewCommandCopy{\pbinom}{\pbinomnull}
\section{Null}

\[
X \quad \pbinom{x}{y} \quad \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \quad X
\]

\end{document}


Comments on the definitions you used

The superscripts must be braced.
\cdots should better be \dots with amsmath.

Final comment
Never ever change the meaning of a command inside the document (except maybe for temporary commands to be used in some environment in order to shorten code): when reading your own code you will never know what variety of \pbinom you're actually using.

Enrico, this is really nice! I have one question about 'never change the meaning of a command inside a document'. Suppose you want to make a run of a book, without the index entries of Chapter 5 -- lets'say. How would you address that without changing the meaning of \index?

@TeXApprentice That's quite a different situation.

What is wrong with \newcommand\pbinom\pbinomshort, other than the fact that it would look prettier with braces? Letting a macro expand to another macro sounds pretty standard TeX to me.

@Gaussler If you’re into code obfuscation, you’re welcome

When you said \renewcommand{\pbinom}{\relax},
\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

equal to
\[ \relax{x}{y} \]
\[ \relax[4]{a}{b} \]

equal to
\[ {x}{y} \]
\[ [4]{a}{b} \]

So you should said,
\renewcommand\pbinom[3][]{}

\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\pbinomshort}[3][2]{(#2 + #3)^#1}
\newcommand{\pbinomlong}[3][2]{(#2^#1 + \cdots + #3^#1)}

\begin{document}

Short:
%\let\pbinom\pbinomshort
\newcommand\pbinom\pbinomshort

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Long:
%\let\pbinom\pbinomlong
\renewcommand\pbinom\pbinomlong

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Null:
\renewcommand\pbinom[3][]{}

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

\end{document}

Of course there is a more elegant solution based on expl3.
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl 
  
  \NewDocumentCommand{\SetPbinomMode}{m}{
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl { #1 }
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{O{2}mm}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl { short }
    {
      (#2 + #3)^#1
    }
    {
      \tl_if_eq:NnT \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl { long }
      {
        (#2^#1 + \cdots + #3^#1)
      }
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Short:
\SetPbinomMode{short}

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Long:
\SetPbinomMode{long}

\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

Null:
\SetPbinomMode{null}


\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

\end{document}



Maaybe an environment for either defining \pbinom or gobbling its content helps doing the trick:
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\tl_new:N \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl 
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetPbinomMode}{m}{ \@bsphack \tl_gset:Nn \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl { #1 } \@esphack }
\msg_new:nnnn { apprentice } { not-in-environment }
              { ’#1’~not~in~pbinoms-environment. }
              { ’#1’~may~only~be~used~in~pbinoms-environment. }
\msg_new:nnnn { apprentice } { PBinomMode-not-set }
              { pbinoms-environment~while~the~pbinom-mode~is~not~set~properly. }
              { Use~the~macro~’#1’~for~setting~the~pbinom-mode~to~one~of~the~values~’short’,~’long’,~’null’~before~calling~’#2’. }
\NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{}{
  \msg_error:nnx { apprentice } { not-in-environment }  { \token_to_str:N \pbinom } 
}
\cs_new:Npn \_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms {  } 
\NewDocumentEnvironment {pbinoms} {} {
  \@bsphack
  \str_case:VnF \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl {
    { short } { \RenewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{O{2}mm}{(##2 + ##3)^{##1}} }
    { long }  { \RenewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{O{2}mm}{(##2^{##1} + \cdots + ##3^{##1})} }
    { null }  { 
                \cs_set:Npn \_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms ##1 \end## 
                   { \_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms:n } 
                \cs_set:Nn \_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms:n 
                   {
                     \str_if_eq:nnTF{##1}{pbinoms}
                                         {\end{pbinoms}}
                                         {\_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms}
                   }
              }
  } {
    \msg_error:nnxx { apprentice } { PBinomMode-not-set } { \token_to_str:N \SetPbinomMode } { \token_to_str:N \begin{pbinoms} }
  }
  \_apprentice_ProbablyGobbleToEndpbinoms\@esphack
}{\str_if_eq:VnF \g__apprentice_pbinom_mode_tl{ null }{\@bsphack}\@Esphack}
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Short: \SetPbinomMode{short}

Text text text.
\begin{pbinoms}
\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]
\end{pbinoms}
Text text text.

\bigskip

Long: \SetPbinomMode{long}

Text text text.
\begin{pbinoms}
\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]
\end{pbinoms}
Text text text.

\bigskip

Null: \SetPbinomMode{null}

Text text text.
\begin{pbinoms}
\[ \pbinom{x}{y} \]
\[ \pbinom[4]{a}{b} \]

\end{pbinoms}
Text text text.

\bigskip

Comparisom with normal text:

Text text text. Text text text.

\end{document}


When it comes to things like changing the values of counters or placing cross referencing labels, you may need to ensure that they get changed/placed even in the case of having things ignored/not typeset.
